# CakePHP - Auth logoutRedirect not working for Admin users

Tags: cakephp

In my cake 2.2 app I have the following beforeFilter() set up in my App Controller:

```
public function beforeFilter() {

    //Configure AuthComponent
    // Admin
    if($this->Auth->user('group_id') == '12') {
        $this->Auth->allow('admin_index'); 
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => FALSE);
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => TRUE);
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => FALSE);

        $this->set("group", "admin");

    // Staff
    }

    if($this->Auth->user('group_id') == '13') {
        $this->Auth->allow('admin_index'); 
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => FALSE);
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => TRUE);
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => FALSE);

        $this->set("group", "staff");
```

So basically I want all users regardles of user group to be sent to /users/login when the session expires. This works for users but any admin users get redirected to admin/users/login and presented with a  Missing method in users controller error (because this isnt an admin method). For some reason the 'admin' => FALSE isnt working.

So, how can I get all users regardless of user type to get redirected to the NON admin method/url of /users/login

```
    // Users
    } 

    if($this->Auth->user('group_id') == '14') {
        $this->Auth->allow(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => FALSE));
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => FALSE);
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => FALSE);
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => FALSE);

        $this->set("group", "user");
    }

    // General logout redirect (including expired session redirect)
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => FALSE);
}
```

Comment: You could hack this with a redirect route in your routes file, but it's not ideal. PS, your capital booleans hurt my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I guess is happening is that the user is not actually login out when the session expires. Unless the user explicitely logs out (executing a lougout action in your UsersController, I'm assuming), like this for example

```
public function logout() {
    ... some code here...
    $this->Session->destroy();
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

that logoutRedirect is probably not going to work.
If the session expires, the user will be unauthorized to view the page, and the redirect is going to go to the Auth->unauthorizedRedirect.

For what you're trying to do, I'd use a method checking if the user is logged in beforeFilter of the AppController

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    if (!$this->Auth->loggedIn() && $this->action != 'login') {
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login', 'admin'=>false));
    }
}
```

or if you want

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    if (!$this->Auth->loggedIn() && $this->action != 'login') {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logoutRedirect);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer - I've tried this and I thought it would work but unfortunately it breaks the session timeout as when I add the above code the session never timesout?! Any other ideas?

Comment: Also using either of your examples results in a redirect loop when I try to manually access the login page.

Comment: I edited the answer to fix the loop, just change the 'login' to your login action name. I find it very weird that the session doesn't timeout, since the code I showed doesn't actually do anything with the session, is just a redirect... I've got the same code in my applications and is kicking me out every few seconds. What are your timeout and security level values in core.php?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function admin_logout() {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Thanks for using Applired.com!'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
    $this->Session->delete('user_to_register');
    $this->Session->destroy();
    $this->Auth->logout();
    return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'login'));
}
```